# How to change wingpanel background color

Tags: wingpanel, elementary

I am using elementray os luna daily build.
And it works fine!

> But if I switch the gtk theme to Zukitwo
>
> The color of the wingpanel is not so pleasant.

[image]
And I try to change color in /usr/share/wingpanel/style/default.css but no lucky

How can I make the wingpanel background color

Comment: We can only support officially-recognized Ubuntu derivatives here on Ask Ubuntu. As such, this question is [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions). You may want to try asking over at the [Unix and Linux StackExchange site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think editing the CSS of the GTK theme for the wingpanel/gnomepanel should work. It worked for mine, but I did a lot of messing around and only wanted to change the opacity by 15%.  Also, I am using a regular Gnome shell theme, don't know if that makes any difference, as there may be multiple files telling the panel how to look.